# Access a string view of an object inside a vector of interfaces C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, stdvector, string-view

I am storing different objects which inherit from the same interface inside a single vector. Those objects have their name stored as a constant string view, which gets its value even before the object gets instantiated. I am able to easily retrieve its name before it gets stored in a vector. However, when I store it inside a vector of interfaces and I access its name again, I get undefined behavior (compiler-dependent).
How can I fix this?

Here's the simplest case which demonstrates my problem. I'm using a compiler which supports C++17 and some features of C++20

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct IFoo {
public:
    virtual ~IFoo() = default;
    const std::string_view name{};
};

struct Foo : public IFoo {
public:
    const std::string_view name = "bar";
};

int main() {
    std::vector<IFoo*> foos;
    Foo *foo = new Foo();
    std::cout << "Name of object before storing: " << foo->name << std::endl;
    foos.push_back(new Foo());
    for (auto foo : foos) {
        std::cout << "Name of object after storing: " << foo->name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It produces the following results:

```
Name of object before storing: bar
Name of object after storing:
```

When I tried changing the vector to `std::vector<Foo*>`, the code ran without any problems. However, this is not a solution, because I want to store multiple types which inherit from the same interface inside a single vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data members can't be overridden. Each `name` in the base and derived classes is a different member and which one you will name in an expression is determined from the static type of the object in the expression, which is `IFoo` if you iterate through the vector, but `Foo` when you refer to `foo` declared as `Foo*`.

Only `virtual` member function have polymorphic behavior. So you need to use one instead:

```
struct IFoo {
public:
    virtual ~IFoo() = default;
    virtual std::string_view name() const = 0;
};

struct Foo : public IFoo {
public:
    std::string_view name() const override {
        return "bar";
    }
};

//...

for (auto foo : foos) {
    std::cout << "Name of object after storing: " << foo->name() << std::endl;
}
```

It would also be a good idea to use `std::unique_ptr<IFoo>` and `std::make_unique<Foo>` instead of `IFoo*` and `new Foo` for memory and exception safety. (Then `auto foo` will need to be `auto& foo` instead.)